# Add multiple entity relationships in OData in one call

Tags: c#, odata

Using OData v4 in my C# Web API, I have the ability to add a relationship between entities.  I have a Supplier object and a Product object and I can add and remove products to/from a supplier.

I've followed the code and examples from this URL under the "Creating a Relationship Between Entities" section:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4

To add product 4 to supplier 6, I simply make this call:

```
PUT: http://xxx.mywebsite.com/Suppliers(6)/Products/$ref

Request Body:
{"@odata.id":"http://xxx.mywebsite.com/Products(4)"}
```

What I would like to do is be able to add multiple products to a supplier in one call.  I've read through the OData documentation but I'm not sure if something like this is supported in the standard.

Thanks!